# R list comprehension if else

Tags: r, list-comprehension

I came from the world of Python. 
I want to only get the positive number and set non-positive number to be zero. 
In Python:

```
>> a = [1,2,3,-1,-2, 0,1,-9]
>> [elem if elem>0 else 0 for elem in a]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Say I have a vector in R, how can I get the same result.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,-1,-2, 0,1,-9)
```

Comment: based on your previous question, you might want `a==0` instead of `a>0`

Comment: I think this thread is more straightforward for people to understand who ask the similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ifelse`

```
> ifelse(a>0, a, 0)
[1] 1 2 3 0 0 0 1 0
```

see `?ifelse` for details.

you can also use `[` to select those values meeting the condition (`a<=0`) and replace them by 0

```
> a[a<=0] <- 0
> a
[1] 1 2 3 0 0 0 1 0
```

see `?"["`.

`a<=0` will give you a boolean vector and you can use it as index to identify those values smaller or equal to 0 and then performing the desired replacement.

Although using either `[` or `ifelse` are the most common, here I give some other alternatives:

```
a[which(a<=0)] <- 0       
#----------------------
a[a %in% 0:min(a)] <- 0    # equivalent to a[!a %in% 0:max(a)] <- 0 
#----------------------
match(a, 1:max(a), nomatch=0 )
#----------------------
pmax(a, 0)
```