# Replace all values lower than threshold in R

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
x <- c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3)
```

I want all values less than 1 to be replaced by 1.

How?

*Is there a no-loop solution?*

Comment: looking around I came across with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11275230/1315767) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19571891/1315767), which can be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pmax` is a good candidate for this

```
  > pmax(x, 1)
    [1] 1 1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 30):

Use logical indexing with replacement:

```
x[ x<1 ] <- 1
```

Comment: That's one of the winners in the benchmarks @Jilber linked to. I used to use `pmax` or `pmin`, but think I'll switch. This is just as readable and has the advantage the I won't incorrectly use `pmin` to set a minimum.

Comment: How to do this for all columns of a datatable? And avoid any errors if there are text 
 values

Answer (score 7):

The other solutions are more appropriate. This is just for fun:

```
(x > 1) * (x - 1) + 1
#[1] 1 1 1 2 3
```

Simple replacement (@Matthew Lundberg) is the most efficient solution:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(pmax(1, x),
               "[<-"(x, x < 1, 1),
               (x > 1) * (x - 1) + 1)

# Unit: microseconds
#                   expr    min      lq  median      uq    max neval
#             pmax(1, x) 15.494 16.2545 16.5165 16.9365 52.165   100
#     `[<-`(x, x < 1, 1)  1.466  1.6920  2.3325  2.7485 23.683   100
#  (x > 1) * (x - 1) + 1  2.084  2.2870  2.7880  3.2080  8.958   100
```

Comment: @lebatsnok This is more readable, but you need two comparisons.

Comment: Ok but here's something even funnier (and perhaps quite readable if you think about it): `(foo <- x <1)*1 + (!foo)*x`

Comment: @lebatsnok Good idea. You can omit the `*1`.

Comment: or `(function(C) C + (!C) * x)(x<1)`

Comment: Revisiting this a few years later, I get a lot less difference between the replacement and your expression for the `x` in the question, but the max is lower for the replacement.  However, if you use a much longer vector the results are a wash for our two approaches, with `pmax` the clear winner.  (`x <- sample(c(-1,0,1,2,3), 1e7, replace=TRUE)`)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be `replace`:

```
x <- c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3)

replace(x, x < 1,1)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 3
```